# How to get the Post request body of a WKWebView in swift

Tags: swift

I went through this post [How can I obtain POST request body from WKWebView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532531/how-can-i-obtain-post-request-body-from-wkwebview-in-swift) .  But it doesn't tell what JS script is being used. I'm new to injecting JS into swift so the post wasn't clear to me.

After I've loaded the request in wkwebview I want to get the http body of the post request. What would be the right way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's related to the bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191362.  It has been already fixed in iOS 13.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out the solution for this problem. To get the contents of the post request html all we need to add is this function:-

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
    {
        PerfomanceMonitor.stopEvent(event: .startToLogin)
        hideActivityIndicator(delayed: true)

```
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("(function() { for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; ++i) { if (typeof document.forms[i]['SAMLResponse'] !== 'undefined')  return document.forms[i]['SAMLResponse'].value;} })();", completionHandler: { (jsonRaw: Any?, error: Error?) in
        guard let jsonString = jsonRaw as? String
        else
        {
            return
        }
        //use the extracted content for use.
    })
}
```

evaluateJavaScript takes the javascript string as an argument which is nothing but the path to the content in your html which you want to extract. I am using a function here cz i need to find one content in the list of all the elements. One can use "document.documentElement.innerHTML" which will give the entire contents.

Answer (score -1):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
  print(navigationAction.request.httpBody)
}
```

Comment: "document.getElementById(\"my-id\").innerHTML". What does this mean? Do i need to add any html doc or any JS script for this to run?

Comment: Also do I need to make the request in JS itself?

Comment: jsonString in the above function comes out to be empty for me and as a result it returns.

Comment: i edited my ans please check it now i hope that works for you

Comment: httpbody is nil. So i was using UIWebView earlier which used to return request.httpbody prefectly. But with WKWebView httpbody is always nil.