# Detect API call and responce in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I have loaded a login page url in WKWebView which is working fine.
and I have api call happening in web page (like login page) So my question : Is it possible get the login JSON data after successful login in WKWebview?

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by login API response? Do you mean JSON?

Comment: Yes, JSON response of api which is happening in webview.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532531/how-can-i-obtain-post-request-body-from-wkwebview-in-swift

Comment: Thanks but Not getting json :(